# I can't get scrollmagic to display the animation

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, scrollmagic, bootstrap-vue

Is there other plugin available that allow us to do something the same as Skrollr?
To Animate elements e.g. pictures while scrolling. but in Vue.js format.
I don't think I convert it right for the one I did.
e.g something link this link.
http://scrollmagic.io/examples/expert/multiple_scroll_directions.html

I have look into Scrollmagic documentation and searcher the web. there is just not much people using vue-scrollmagic.

In Template:

```
 <div class="spacer s0"></div>
<div  class="text-center">
    <img id="animate"
    class="img-fluid iq-mobile-img"
    src="img.png"
    alt="Smartphone"
>
</div>
```

In script:

```
methods: {
    sphone() {
      var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

      // build scene
      var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: "#multiDirect",
        duration: 400,
        offset: 250,
      })
        .setPin("#animate")
        .addIndicators({ name: "resize" }) // add indicators (requires plugin)
        .addTo(controller);

  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(sphone); //this.
  }
```

No error message is shown. am a newbie. so I may have not notice it. 
I do see warnings, but is not related to scroll magic.

I expect the it to be animated while scrolling. but it did not animate; which is wrong.

Comment: Please edit your title, as your title stand right now I would be inclined to flag the question as off topic (as asking for a library or other off-site resource is off topic)

Comment: sure. let me see if I can change it. ..

Comment: Done. changed. but it does not change the fact that I am looking for other tools that can work like it. So I'll very much appreciate it if there is any kind soul willing to provide such suggestion.